# check for nil and extract data from dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, dictionary

If the user provides a date value I store it in a dictionary:

```
let dict:Dictionary<String, Any> = ["fromDate":fromDate as Any]
```

If the user does not provide a date value I store it in a dictionary like this:

```
let dict:Dictionary<String, Any> = ["fromDate": [:] ]
```

I tried to retrieve the value  from the dictionary inside `cellForRowAt` function like this:

```
let dict:Dictionary<String, Any> = allDates[indexPath.row]
guard let fromDate:String = getDateString(createdDate: dict["fromDate"] as! Date) != nil else {
        fromDate:String = "None"
}
cell.fromDateLabel.text = getTimeStringISO8601(createdDate: fromDate)
```

This is my date to string function

```
func getDateString(createdDate:Date) -> String{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter.string(from: createdDate)
}
```

I get error on the guard  statement:

> Type ‘String’ is not optional value can never be nil

How can I check if date is not nil and get the date converted and if date is nil skip it and put in a statement as “None” instead of Date?

Comment: `let dict:Dictionary<String, Any> = ["fromDate": [:] ]` -> this will cause some conversion problem later. Change this to `let dict:Dictionary<String, Any> = ["fromDate": nil ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in guard statement is because the method `getDateString:` not returns an optional value. you are checking the return value of that method which will never be nil as per definition. You need to check date value from dict as it is optional.

try like,

```
var fromDate = "None" 
if let dateVal = dict["fromDate"] as? Date {
    fromDate = getDateString(createdDate: dateVal)
    cell.fromDateLabel.text = getTimeStringISO8601(createdDate: fromDate)
} else {
    cell.fromDateLabel.text = fromDate
}
```

Comment: I started using guard and found that I had to return if it failed whereas my logic has to continue processing other fields. This solution with if let worked for me. Though there are several correct answers, I choose this because it is appropriate and first one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let dict:Dictionary<String, Any> = allDates[indexPath.row]

if let date = dict["fromDate"] as? Date {
    // the date is not nil
    //here you can formate your date
}else{
   //the date is nil, make additional stuff here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add optional to return value of your method

```
**func getDateString(createdDate:Date) -> String?**


class UIViewController: UIViewController {

       guard let fromDate:String = getDateString(createdDate: Date())  else {

          return

        }
    }


    func getDateString(createdDate:Date) -> String?{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter.string(from: createdDate)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use unwrapping right do it like this:

```
let dict:Dictionary<String, Any> = allDates[indexPath.row]
guard let fromDate: String = getDateString(createdDate: dict["fromDate"] as? Date) else   {
    fromDate:String = "None"
}
 cell.fromDateLabel.text = getTimeStringISO8601(createdDate: fromDate)
```

and you function should look like this:

```
    func getDateString(createdDate:Date?) -> String?{
      if let createdDate = createdDate {
         let formatter = DateFormatter()
         formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
         formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
         formatter.locale = Locale.current
         formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
         formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
         return formatter.string(from: createdDate)
      }

      return nil
   }
```